# Retrieving JSON from site equals NULL

Tags: php, json

```
$url="https://alcurex.com/api/market.php?pair=mrc_ltc&price=buy";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo $json;
var_dump($data);
```

Results in a null response. However when you visit the page you get a html read out of

```
{
    "pair": MRC_LTC,
    "time": "2014-07-23 07:34:54,
    "price": 0.00000017,
    "volume": 558.99741176,
    "type": Buy
},
```

Comment: So, do you think the output of `var_dump()` is going to produce valid JSON?

Comment: I think this was where I last left off. I tried all manner of things to get the values to come back as an array I could access.

Comment: Ok, you need to be clearer about how you're working with the result of your script and where you're seeing this "null"

Comment: It's not working because the JSON from alcurex.com is invalid... It appears to be handwritten..? It's missing quotes everywhere, and the date has one at the start but not at the end... `json_encode()` wouldn't do that to you - must be self inflicted.

Comment: ... and that folks, is why you **never** roll your own JSON

Comment: Bollocks. That's what I thought but not being 100% confident I couldn't be sure. Gah. I could parse the result reading the characters I suppose? Better off getting them to fix it though.

Comment: You *could* write something to add the necessary quotes to this, but you're write - you're **much** better off telling them to sort it out from their end. You can't be expected to work with invalid markups or formatting.

Comment: Just so I know, what did you use to determine it was crap JSON? A JSON validator or just tribal knowledge?

Comment: You can validate your JSON with [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is not valid JSON format.

> { "pair": MRC_LTC, "time": "2014-07-23 07:34:54, "price": 0.00000017, "volume": 558.99741176, "type": Buy },

You could check it from Firefox console, correct JSON should be this:

```
var s = {
  "pair": "MRC_LTC",
  "time": "2014-07-23 07:34:54",
  "price": 0.00000017,
  "volume": 558.99741176,
  "type": "Buy"
 };
```

**Errors:**

1. Missing " for pair, time and type
2. Unnecessary comma at the end of string

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems with this JSON:

- pair value is not a valid type, if it should be string, it's missing quotes
- time has string start quote but does not end it
- type value is not a valid type, if it should be string, it's missing quotes

This is a valid JSON:

```
{
    "pair": "MRC_LTC",
    "time": "2014-07-23 07:34:54",
    "price": 0.00000017,
    "volume": 558.99741176,
    "type": "Buy"
}
```